# Data-push attribute in kaminari or will_paginate pagination?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, kaminari

I am using pagination with kaminari gem or will_paginate, but i have request check whether request is wiselink, as my pagination request is not wiselink its sending me back to home page of my app as i specified it in check request, but how can i give simple html request using data-push attribute. I am trying to use this command but its not working

`<%= will_paginate @reports, options: {remote: true, class: 'ajax_index', data: {pjax: true} } %>`

or

`<%= paginate @reports, options: {remote: true, class: 'ajax_index', data: {pjax: true} } %>`

For both the gems are not working. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I got this working. You have to create a separate view for Kaminari with this command

```
rails g kaminari:views default
```

and add this

`:remote => remote,:'data-push' => 'true', :'data-target' => '#AdminPanel--PartialRenders'`

to your every view page like first,last,next an previous. You will already have span tag in those files, you just have to add these more tags inside that.

Comment: In data-target section give your on content which you want to use as wise links.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the first one, can you include the code used  at reportscontroler